# Strange equality involving the sum of squares of a finite set in Euclidean vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, descriptive-statistics

**Conjecture.** Let $Q$ be a finite subset of a finite-dimensional Euclidean vector space $V$ and let $p \in V$. Then
$$\sum_{q \in Q} ||q - p||^2 = \sum_{q \in Q} \left(||q - \mathbb{E}[Q]||^2 + ||\mathbb{E}[Q] - p||^2 \right)$$

Note that for an individual $q \in Q$ it is not true in general that  $||q - p||^2 = ||q - \mathbb{E}[Q]||^2 + ||\mathbb{E}[Q] - p||^2$. I tried many numerical examples and it always worked.

Can anyone prove or disprove this conjecture?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @aschepler you're right, I reformulated the post because the question was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

number the $q_i$   from $1$ to $n$   Then name $T = \sum q_i^2 = \sum q_i \cdot q_i $   which is scalar

Then $S = \sum q_i $ which is a vector with $E = S/n$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ \sum (p - q_i)^2 = T - 2 p \cdot S + n p^2 $$

$$ \sum ( p - \frac{1}{n}S)^2 = n p^2 - 2 p \cdot S + \frac{1}{n}  S^2  $$

$$ \sum ( q_i - \frac{1}{n} S)^2 = T - \frac{1}{n}  S^2  $$

and the second plus third line equals the first

Comment: Is $\mathbb{E}[Q]$ the only point $e$ such that $\sum_{q \in Q}\|q-p\|^{2}=\sum_{q \in Q}\left(\|q-e\|^{2}+\|e-p\|^{2}\right)$ ?

Comment: I also figured out that the identity in question follows from $\sum_{q \in Q} \langle p, q\rangle = \sum_{q \in Q} \left(  \langle q, \mathbb{E}[Q] \rangle -\langle \mathbb{E}[Q], \mathbb{E}[Q]\rangle + \langle \mathbb{E}[Q], p\rangle \right)$